# Partition the points

Tags: geometry

Given an even number of points in general positions on the plane (that is, no three points co-linear), can you partition the points into pairs and connect the two points of each pair with a single straight line such that the straight lines do not overlap?

Comment: Meaning that no two straight lines overlap? Or there is no point at which *all* of the lines cross simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the result is true for $2n$ points. We show it is true for $2(n+1)$ points.

Let $S$ be a set of $2(n+1)$ points. Draw a straight line $\ell$ such that all points of $S$ are on one side of the line, and none is on the line.

Move the line $\ell$ parallel to itself, slowly towards $S$. After a while, it just meets $S$, say at point $P$. If it also meets $S$ at another point $Q$, be happy. Else rotate the line slowly about $P$ until it first meets $S$ at another point $Q$.

Join $PQ$ by a line segment. By the induction hypothesis, the rest of the points of $S$ can be split into pairs, and the pairs joined by non-intersecting line segments. By the choice of $P$ and $Q$, these line segments do not meet $PQ$.

**Remark:** In fewer words, the convex hull of $S$ is a polygon. We can let $P$ and $Q$ be any two consecutive vertices of the polygon.

Comment: Or choose the line $\ell$ so it's not parallel to any line determined by two points in $S$. The moving line crosses the points of $S$ one by one. Stop at any point where there are an even (nonzero) number of points on either side.

Comment: @bof: That is a nice way of doing the induction.

Comment: Mathematical induction is hardly needed here. Perhaps the simplest way to present the proof: Rotate $S$ so that no two points lie on a vertical line, index the points from left to right as $P_1,\dots,P_n$, and draw the segments $P_1P_2,P_3P_4,\dots,P_{2n-1}P_{2n}$. The same argument shows that a finite set of points in $R^n$, if its cardinality is divisible by $k$, can be partitioned into $k$-element set whose convex hulls are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are a finite number of ways to partition the points into pairs. Choose a partition which minimizes the sum of the squares of the lengths of the resulting line segments. If two of the segments intersect, it's clear from the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) that the sum could be made smaller. ("General position" is irrelevant for this; all you need is an even number of distinct points in the plane.)