# N points and N perpendiculars

Tags: geometry

This is actually a set of two problems: (in one question, I believe it is useful and convenient to analyse them together)

---

### Problem A

> $N$ arbitrary points are given in a plane (all different). $N$ arbitrary lines are also given in the same plane (no two of them are parallel). Show that there exist a set of $N$ perpendiculars from points to lines such that there is a single perpendicular from each point, there is a single perpendicular to each line, and no two such perpendiculars intersect.

---

### Problem B

> Is the analoguous claim valid if the word "line" is replaced with "circle", and "parallel" with "concentric"?

---

NOTE: *"A perpendicular" in the context of these problems means a segment going from a point to a line/circle (of course perpendicular to the line/circle).*

I know the answer to Problem A, but not to Problem B. I am not attaching the answer to Problem A (for the time being), since I do not want to spoil possible different approaches.

I appreciate any hint/insight/idea of yours.

Comment: Problem B feels like a 'plane inversion' of Problem A, since inversions preserve angles and map lines to circles. That may not be sufficiently generic, though.

Comment: How is it possible that "no two such perpendiculars intersect". Are these line segments, or lines? Otherwise, the perpendicular lines are not parallel, so much intersect.

Comment: @Calvin, they (perpendiculars) are segments, I am going to update the question to be clear.

Comment: @Semiclassical Potential gap is that "parallel" doesn't invert to "concentric". Also, you only go from a line to a circle if the center of inversion is on the line.

Comment: What if all the circle's centre and all the point are on the same line? Does that count as "intersect" if the line segments drawn share more than 1 point?

Comment: @Gina This looks like a valid counterexample.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557332/partition-the-points?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for Problem A:**

Consider the $N!$ sets of perpendicular line segments where each of the $N$ points are uniquely joined to one of the $N$  lines. Take the set with minimal sum of lengths.

Claim: No two perpendicular line segments intersect.

**Hint for Problem B:**

This problem is not true. Find a configuration of 2 circles and 2 lines where it must intersect.

However, it is sufficient if no pair of points and pair of centers are collinear.

[There's an error in this argument which reflects the need for the extra condition:

A line segment is perpendicular to a circle only if it passes through the center of the circle.

Consider the $N!$ sets of lines where each of the $N$ points are uniquely joined to one of the $N$ (distinct by assumption) circle centers. Take the set with minimal sum of lengths.

Claim: No two line segments intersect.

Note: This claim is not true. However, it is true if we add the condition that "no pair of points and pair of centers are collinear."]

Comment: That's great, you even found the extra assumption that makes claim from Problem B valid!